# MonoDroid Programmatically setting edittext to password mode

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext

Does anyone know how to programmatically set an edittext control to password mode in Mono for Android. The normal settransformation method doesn't seem to be available in MonoDroid.

Answer (score 4):

Properties that start with Get and Set in the Android APIs will have the Get and Set prefix removed in the MonoDroid version to be more consistent with c# property naming.

You should be able to do the following:

```
etEditText.TransformationMethod = Android.Text.Method.PasswordTransformationMethod.Instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to get your EditText field and set it:

```
passwordEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.your_id_name);        
passwordEditText.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText | Android.Text.InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
```

Also, just an FYI be sure to handle screen rotation properly.